# Flutter build stuck after log: Successfully started process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat''

Tags: flutter

When I run

```
flutter build apk -v
```

the build process gets stuck after the log:

```
Successfully started process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat''
```

But, "flutter run" with device is building debug apk. Already tried flutter clean, flutter doctor, flutter upgrade, disabling antivirus.
Please advice, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
flutter build apk --split-per-abi
```

https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android

Comment: still same :( Stuck after "Successfully started process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat''"